# Segfault and logic errors

Tags: c, linked-list

I am making a linked list program which utilizes several functions to simplify adding or removing nodes from the list. I believe that my logic is alright with allocating and adding a new node but I am still getting a seg fault. Could you look over my logic and explain what is causing the seg fault? I am very inexperienced with linked lists. Thank you!

This is my function declarations

```
#define SIMPLELL_H

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
  int data;
  struct Node *next;
}node_t;

node_t* head;

void printList();
void append(int num);
void addFront(int num);
void deleteList();
void removeNode(int num);
int length();



#endif
```

This is the function definitions

```
void printList(){
  // declare temp to traverse the LL and print each value
  node_t *temporary = head;
  while(temporary != NULL){
    printf("%d, ", temporary->data);
    temporary = temporary->next;
  }
  if (head == NULL){
    printf("This list is empty.\n");
  }
}
void append(int num){
  //declare temporary pointer to traverse LL
  node_t *tmp = head;
  node_t *prev = NULL;
  //malloc the new node
  node_t *new = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  if(head == NULL){
    //initialize the new node
    new->data = num;
    new->next = NULL;

    head->next = new;
  }
  else{
    //initialize the new node
    new->data = num;
    new->next = NULL;
    //loop to traverse to the last value in the node
    while(tmp != NULL){
      prev = tmp;
      tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    prev->next = new;
  }
}
void addFront(int num){
  //allocate memory for new node and allocate local variable equal to head
  node_t *new = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  new->data = num;
  new->next = head;
  head = new;
}
void deleteList(){
  node_t *tmp = head;
  node_t *prev = NULL;
  while(tmp != NULL){
    prev = tmp;
    tmp = tmp->next
    free(prev);
  }
}
void removeNode(int num){
//temp is used to traverse the ll until I find the node with the value
//then the previous value is linked to the next value removing the middle value.
  node_t *temp = head;
  node_t *prev = NULL;
  if(head == NULL){
    printf("List is not initialized\n");
    return;
  }
  while(temp->data != num){
    prev = temp;
    temp = temp->next;
    if (temp->data == num){
      prev->next = temp->next;
      free(prev);
    }
    else{
      printf("Value is not in the list\n");
      return;
    }

}
int length(){
  int length = 0;
  node_t *temp = head;
  while (temp != NULL){
    length += 1;
    temp = temp->next;
  }
  return length;
}
```

This is the driver function which I should not have to change

```
#include "SimpleLL.h"
#include "SimpleLL.c"
int main()
{
  /*head is a global variable*/
  head = NULL;
  int size =0;
  removeNode(1);
  append(2);
  append(3);
  addFront(1);
  append(4);
  printList();
  size = length();
  printf("size now %d\n",size);
  removeNode(8);
  printList();
  removeNode(1);
  printList();
  removeNode(4);
  printList();
  deleteList();
  printList();
  size = length();
  printf("size after deletion %d\n",size);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `/*head is a global variable*/` That's a very bad idea.

Comment: Consider what happens in `append` when the "list" is empty. What value does `prev` has?

Comment: It should just be ```NULL``` correct? In this case should I use an if statement to make a case for when ```head/prev``` is NULL?

Comment: That would help. Also note that `printList` will always print `"This list is empty.\n"` at the end. This may not be the expected behaviour.

Comment: So I have edited my append function to include that if statement, however, I am still getting a seg fault. I know that this seg fault occurs in the append function, however I am still uncertain what is causing it. I assume it is my malloc function but I am unsure as to why it is causing a seg fault.

Comment: `if(head == NULL){ /* ... */  head->next = new; }` I'm afraid you have to rethink this. I'd strongly suggest to stop writing code, for the moment, and start using pen and paper to figure out all the possible cases and relative approaches.

Comment: `#include "SimpleLL.c"` You should not include a C file unless you have a really good reason to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`removeNode` contains no test for reaching the end of the list.  So if the value is not found in the list, it will dereference the NULL pointer at the end and crash.

This will be the case in the very first test, which attempts to remove a node when the list is empty, as well as for `removeNode(8)`.

Your `removeNode` function also needs to `free()` the node it removed.  Currently it is freeing the node that came after the one removed, which is still in the list and will cause undefined behavior when you access it later.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have now fixed that but my function still seg faults after. I think that there is an issue with my add node function but I am not sure what it is. I will update my post shortly

Comment: @Arock475: You haven't fixed it - now what happens if the list isn't empty but the desired number isn't in it?  As will be the case with `removeNode(8)`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct I did not think of that. Thank you

Comment: @Arock475: Your `free()` is incorrect - see edit.

Comment: I think that I have fixed the free() issue as well as fixed it so that if the value is not in the linked list that it will properly print an error message and exit.

Comment: @Arock475: So now what happens if the value *is* present in the list, but is not the first element?  Your current code will not remove it.  The fundamental problem is looping on `while(temp->data != num)`.  This needs to *also* include a test for whether the end has been reached, more like `while(temp != NULL && temp->data != num)`.